# Infinitely long proofs

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Take a proof to be a sequence (I'm working in Hilbert style system for simplicity). I have heard of infinitely long proofs.

When we speak of infinitely long proofs, are we talking about proofs indexed by $\mathbb N$, or some other ordinal? Or perhaps uncountably long proofs?

What kind of use can you think of for such proofs (especially proofs indexed by something larger than $\mathbb N$)?

EDIT: If we regard computations as derivations in some formal system, then an endless loop could be an example of an infinitely long derivation? But I think that's not an example of a derivation that needs to be indexed by something bigger than $\mathbb N$.

Comment: [They can be indexed by ordinals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_logic), assuming AC.

Comment: regarding endless loops: could be.  One situation where modeling with higher ordinals makes sense is computation with oracles.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's actually vastly easier to view proofs as trees in this context, so I'll do that.

Generally, an "infinitely long proof" is more accurately a *well-founded infinitely-branching tree* (or something morally equivalent) - the idea being that we're working in some [infinitary logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/) (or some logic of similar nature) where the basic deductive steps might involve infinitely many hypotheses. "Well-founded" means that the tree has no infinite paths, that is, no infinite regress: a node is "justified" by its immediate successors, with the root being the conclusion of the proof.

Now the point is that there is a notion associated to a well-founded tree which serves as a decent proxy for proof length - namely, the **rank** of the tree. Given a well-founded tree $T$, there is a unique function $\nu$ from the nodes of $T$ to the ordinals such that for each node $\alpha$ we have $$\nu(\alpha)=\sup\{\nu(\beta)+1: \alpha\prec \beta\}$$ (we take the supremum of the emptyset to be $0$, which means that $\nu(\alpha)=0$ for every terminal node $\alpha$). When we speak of the "length" of a proof in an infinitary system, this is what we (usually) mean. **There are well-founded trees of arbitrary ordinal rank** - while we generally are interested in at-most-countably-branching trees, which always have rank $<\omega_1$, we're not a priori limited to such.

As for their application, they show up in the study of infinitary logic in several ways (and [Barwise's book](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pl/1235418475) has a good section on them) but they're also used to study classical first-order logic by replacing a complicated finitary system by an infinitary system which nonetheless has some better features; this happens with reasonable frequency in **ordinal analysis**, see e.g. [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-63385-5_29)).

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you could prove Peano's Fifth Axiom, a.k.a. the Axiom of Induction.

Comment: This is a good thought but could use some elaboration.

Comment: Ah so something like a proof by cases? $\omega$ cases for induction on $\omega$ and a higher ordinal number of cases for induction on a higher ordinal?

Comment: You'd need an appropriate rule in the infinitary logic.  But the obvious rule is to derive $\forall\,n\;P(n)$ from $P(0)$, $P(1)$, $P(2)$, etc, and then each instance of the induction axiom schema can be proved (without using that schema).  And in a second-order logic, the induction axiom can be proved as a single statement, by universalizing $P$.  So yes.

Comment: @stranger The infinitary rule Toby Bartels is referring to is the [$\omega$-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory#%CF%89-logic): similar to the finite $\wedge$-introduction rule, "From $A$ and $B$ infer $A\wedge B$," the $\omega$-rule says "From $A(n)$ for each $n$ infer $\forall x A(x)$." There are actually many different kinds of $\omega$-rule, since it's usually more interesting to look at weaker versions of the full $\omega$-rule, and these come up a lot in proof theory.

Comment: I don't know much about this topic myself, so if one of you (@TobyBartels or @NoahSchweber) wanted to expand this into a full length post I would be happy to delete mine.

Comment: Well, I only know about the full $\omega$-rule, so @Noah Schweber knows more than I do.